# Reconstructing an object from its shadow

Tags: vector-spaces, differential-calculus, image-processing

I'm looking into the section "Reconstructing an object from its shadow" in the book *Introduction to the Mathematics of Medical Imaging* by Charles L. Epstein.

**I have two questions**

1. The tangent point is expressed as a vector which contain two component. The shadow function $h$ multiplied with the orthogonal vector and an $s$ function multiplied with the direction vector. Can anyone tell me why do we have this equation, and what does the $s$ function mean?
2. And also why do we have $h'D(e) - s(e) = 0$ when it is parallel to the direction vector $\hat \omega$?

[image for question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zWGZ.png)

[image for question 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pE7d.png)

Comment: [Cross posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885008/reconstructing-an-object-from-its-shadow).